# Sequence in space $l_2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I need to check some properties of the following sequence.
$z_n = $$\sqrt[] {n} e_n$, where $e_n$ - canonical basis of $l_2$.

1)What norm of $z_n$?

$$||z_n|| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sqrt[] {n}e_n|^2 = \sqrt[] {n}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |e_n|^2 = \sqrt[] {n}$$

is it $\sqrt[] {n}$ ? If no -> why?

2)To which vector converges $z_n$ coordinate-by-coordinate?

$z = (0,0,...,\infty)$ here is an infinity amount of zeros. Right?

3)$z$ from above belongs to $l_2$?

No, because it's sum $= \infty$

4)$z_n$ converges to vector $z$ in topology generated by the norm?

Any hint or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to conflate some of this:

1)
$$
\lVert z_n \rVert = \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \lvert \sqrt{n} (e_n)_i \rvert^2 } = \sqrt{n}
$$
Note that this is because $(e_n)_i = \delta_{in}$. So you can see what happens when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

2)
For every coordinate $i$ and index $n$ it holds that $\sqrt{n}(e_n)_i$ equals $0$ if $n>i$. So every coordinate converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

3)
$z=0$ clearly belongs to $\ell^2$.

4)
It does not converge. Convergent sequences are bounded. $z_n$ is clearly not bounded.

Comment: What means $(e_n)_i = \delta_{in}$? (I understand that $e_n = (0,0,0,...,1,0,...)$ where 1 stays on place with index = n.)

Comment: Exactly. $\delta_{in}$ is the so called Kronecker delta. It means that it is $0$ if $i \neq n$ and $1$ if $\delta = n$.

Comment: And, actually, are you sure that this norm with sqrt right? It says in book that it is same, but without sqrt.

Comment: Yes it is definetly correct. Maybe the book talks about $\lVert z_n \Vert^2$, i.e. the squared norm

Comment: Sorry, may i ask one more question? I am interested if this $z_n$ converges to $z$ in weak topology?

Comment: Weakly convergent sequences are bounded.